# Php remove folder cross domain

Tags: php, linux, codeigniter

I have a system where all the clients and their data use one domain, and the main admin back-end that I will be using is on another domain, both on the same server.

I have been looking at php's `rmdir($dir);` and some of linux's `system('/bin/rm -rf ' . escapeshellarg($dir));` but they only work for files and folders in the same domain as I am currently using.

The purpose for this is when I want to remove a client, I want to remove all info for them including their DB and data folder.

The folder is located on `public_html/data`, so is on the root folder for the domain.

Can this only be done if both sites are on the same domain?

Thanx in advance!

Comment: Why not use an external API with an endpoint so that you can just hit a URL and have the other software perform the removal for you?

Comment: not a bad idea, never thought of that, will check if I can make it work and let you know, thanx!

Comment: It's not problem of cross-domain. You needs to manage client data folders by absolute path (using readpath() and store to somewhere that backend can read), and remove them by rmdir(). Please consider about the permission.

Comment: the permissions are 777 for the data folders, but will see what I can do with readpath

Comment: did yo mean realpath? I cannot find a readpath php function